# How do I put a url_for function inside of a jinja2 for-loop if there are two bracket references that will confuse the loop

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```html
{% for display in images %}
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/{{ display.name }}') }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Do you see how the {{ display.name }} is inside the also-bracketed {{ url_for }} function?  Is there a way I could make this work so I could loop images?

Answer (score 3):

```
{% for display in images %}
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/'+display.name) }}">
{% endfor %}
```

You can directly use it as a variable in the function call for `url_for` as given above. Using `{{}}` is only for printing out something into HTML.